# How do I run jQuery load method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

hello I want using jquery load method

my file ( testPage.cshtml)

```
mvcProject
    Views
        Base
            index.cshtml ( <div id="test"></div> )
            testPage.cshtml
            page.html
```

client side ( not working...)

```
 jQuery('#test').load('/Views/testPage.cshtml'); or
 jQuery('#test').load('/Views/page.html');
```

but I'm trying again , is working..

mvcProject ( root )

```
            testPage.html  ( <div id="test"></div> )


jQuery('#test').load('testPage.html');
```

How do I get the url address? Is there something similar?
example :

```
var html = findPath(testPage.html)
 jQuery('#test').load(html);
```

thank you ..

Comment: Are you sure you are wrapping this into a `jQuery(document).ready(function() { //code here });`  ?

Comment: hello no only I want to load into html div content

Comment: I think that client side don't know filesystem path...i think that you must implement your own findPath or resolve url path server side.

Comment: yes I use it jQuery(document).ready(function() {  }

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to give relative path to load() method, as you passed `/Views/page.html` it was expecting it that directory your current page situated contains a folder Views which has page.html file but actually it was not because both file are in same directory:

> A relative path is a path relative to the working directory of the user or application, so the full absolute path will not have to be given.

[Here is absolute vs relative path details.](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

and also put all your jQuery code in ready block:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  //put you code here
});
```